# Invalid Initializer When I try to call function from another function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, initialization, function-call

I have two functions. One that returns the part of the string for me. Don't ask me why I'm doing it inside a function because I want to run this inside a thread.

When I try to get the return value from another function that will return and store it inside a variable an error occur. It says Invalid initializer.

Long time no coding with C programming language. So I'm sorry if there are some basic mistakes.

Can anyone help with this problem?

My code goes like below:

```
void *encrypt(char data[])
{
     //code goes here
    return data[];
}

void *firstThread(void *message)
{
    code goes here
    .
    .
    .
    char message[40] = encrypt(data);//returns Invalid Inıtıalızer
}
```

Comment: You cannot assign pointers to arrays!

Comment: You cannot assign a pointer to a `char` array. You can only initialize it to a literal string or a sequence of numeric values compatible with `char`.

Comment: `return data[]` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Barmar is it okay with return data;

Comment: how can ı take the return data from encrypt function and store it inside firstThread function?? can you tell me Bodo??

Comment: If the function modifies the `data` array in place, there's no need to return it or assign to another variable. Just use the argument array after calling the function.

Comment: yeah Thank you Barmar seems like your Suggestion solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The both functions are invalid.

In the first function the return expression is wrong

```
return data[];
```

You have to write

```
return data;
```

The compiler adjusts the function parameter having the array type to pointer to the array element type like

```
void *encrypt(char *data);
```

This pointer is returned from the function casted to the type `void *`.

In the second function you are trying to initialize an array with a pointer of the type `void *`

```
char message[40] = encrypt(data);//returns Invalid Inıtıalızer
```

You may not do that. Instead you could write for example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

void *firstThread(void *message)
{
    code goes here
    .
    .
    .
    char message[40];

    strcpy( message, encrypt(data) );
}
```

provided that the returned pointer from the function `encript` points to a string. Otherwise you need to supply some way also the size of the pointed array to use the function `memcpy` instead of `strcpy`.

Or you could just declare within the function `firstThread` a pointer provided that the pointed array will be still alive

```
void *firstThread(void *message)
{
    code goes here
    .
    .
    .
    char *message = encrypt(data);
}
```

Comment: yeah, you are right Vlad But ı didn't code it like that someone edited the Code So I'm sorry for this. In my code it is return data; So thank you

Comment: @YusufGuner Just a side note: `strcpy` might be critical if the encryption doesn't retain the terminating null character. Then, though, question arises how you would propagate the encrypted data's size...

Comment: @Aconcagua ı try to use memcpy() and it didn't return me an error for now.

Comment: @YusufGuner memcpy requires three arguments. You need to know the size of the array pointed to by the returned pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign pointers to arrays!

If you want to initialise arrays you need to provide an appropriate initialiser like:

```
char message[40] = { 1, 2, 3 /* rest will be 0 };
```

If you want the array to contain data you receive via some pointer you need to explicitly copy it:

```
char message[40];
memcpy(message, encrypt(data), 0);
```

Well, in above statement *nothing* will be copied. Instead of `0` you need to provide the minimum of `message`'s size and the size of the data returned by your function.

Apart from you have a duplicate variable name: `message` as parameter and `message` as local variable.

Comment: Thank you! I will consider your suggestions and I'm gonna try to implement them to my code.